# Automatically inject WebJarAssets in Play 2.5 HTML template?

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt, webjars, playframework-2.5

In my Play HTML template inside my `custom` module, I have the following line of code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="@controllers.core.routes.WebJarAssets.at(WebJarAssets.locate("jquery.min.js"))"></script>
```

This references a `WebJarAssets` class in the `core` module that looks like this:

```
package controllers.core

import javax.inject._
import play.api.http.HttpErrorHandler
import play.api.{Environment, Configuration}

class WebJarAssets @Inject()(errorHandler: HttpErrorHandler, configuration: Configuration, environment: Environment) extends controllers.WebJarAssets(errorHandler, configuration, environment)
```

Please note that I have also included the following line in `build.sbt` in the `custom` module:

```
"org.webjars" %% "webjars-play" % "2.5.0",
```

When starting the application, I receive the following error:

```
[error] /Users/john/DemoProject/modules/custom/app/views/custom/templates/main.scala.html:36: not found: value WebJarAssets
[error]     <script type="text/javascript" src="@controllers.core.routes.WebJarAssets.at(WebJarAssets.locate("jquery.min.js"))"></script>
[error]                                                                                  ^
```

Judging from the implementation of WebJarAssets in earlier releases, there was no need to implement and inject an own controller for this (for example, see this [tutorial](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-playful-web-dev-1-trs-bluemix/)).

What am I doing wrong? Do I even need a `WebJarAssets` class for this (as I need web jar assets in many modules, I added this for now in the `core` module). Furthermore, why do I need to manually inject it in the template and why is it not automatically resolved?

In case you wonder what manually inject means for me:

```
@(title: String, webJarAssets: WebJarAssets)(content: Html)(implicit messages:Messages)
<script type="text/javascript" src="@controllers.core.routes.WebJarAssets.at(webJarAssets.locate("jquery.min.js"))"></script>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Before `webjars-play` `2.5.0` there was a static method that you could use in your templates.  Since Play has been moving away from global state / static methods, that was removed from `webjars-play` and now you need to inject `WebJarAssets`.  Unfortunately the Twirl templates don't support injection yet.  So you have to inject it into your controller and then pass it to your template.  Here is a full sample app that does this: https://github.com/webjars/webjars-play/tree/master/test-project

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. However, I think this new approach introduced [circular dependency issues](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37057137/how-to-prevent-circular-dependencies-when-using-webjarassets-play-2-5).

Comment: I don't like this approach. This is degradation.

Comment: @KhwarezmShah Can you file an issue on https://github.com/webjars/webjars-play with more details?

Comment: @JamesWard Yes, sure

Comment: If I understand correctly, this means that during migration to 2.5 most likely every single controller and view will have to be updated with this parameter. :(

Comment: Is there any view on if and when Twirl will support injection?

Comment: It looks like it is supported now: https://github.com/playframework/twirl/pull/100

Answer (score 2):

It can write like that.

controller:

```
class Application @Inject()(implicit webJarAssets: WebJarAssets,
                          val messagesApi: MessagesApi, materializer: Materializer)
  extends Controller with I18nSupport {
```

template:

```
@(title: String)(content: Html)(implicit messages: Messages, webJarAssets: WebJarAssets)
<script type='text/javascript' src='@routes.WebJarAssets.at(webJarAssets.locate("jquery.min.js"))'></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

As @james-ward said in `play-2.5.12` with `twirl-1.2.0` you can declare inject dependencies in templates but they will become classes and not objects that complicates the reference to the templates from other ones.

The changes are:

**project/plugins.sbt**

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-twirl" % "1.2.0")
```

**main.scala.html**

```
@this(webJarAssets: WebJarAssets)

@(title: String)(content: Html)(implicit messages:Messages)
<script type="text/javascript" 
  src="@controllers.core.routes.WebJarAssets.at(webJarAssets.locate("jquery.min.js"))">
</script>
```

Note that a caller of the main template should also declare a constructor **mainClient.scala.html**:

```
@this(mainRef: main)
@(...)

content
@main("title"){   }
content
```