# How to activate circular dependencies in Play 2.5?

Tags: scala, playframework, guice, webjars, playframework-2.5

This question originates from a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37057137/how-to-prevent-circular-dependencies-when-using-webjarassets-play-2-5) that I asked two days ago. I implemented my own error handler which extends `DefaultHttpErrorHandler`. `DefaultHttpErrorHandler` extends `HttpErrorHandler` which is also used as a parameter `errorHandler: HttpErrorHandler` in the `WebJarAssets` class. First I thought I had a flaw in my design, but [James Ward](https://stackoverflow.com/users/77409/james-ward) commented that *it seems like that I am doing things right*.

Long story short, I need to know how I can activate circular dependencies. Unfortunately, there is no example code listed in the [Play documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/Migration25#Guice-injector-and-Guice-builder-changes), so I have no idea where I should set `disableCircularProxies(false)`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need a custom `GuiceApplicationLoader` like:

```
import play.api.ApplicationLoader
import play.api.inject.guice.{GuiceApplicationLoader, GuiceApplicationBuilder}

class CustomApplicationLoader extends GuiceApplicationLoader {
  override protected def builder(context: ApplicationLoader.Context): GuiceApplicationBuilder = {
    super.builder(context).disableCircularProxies(false)
  }
}
```

And tell Play to use it in `application.conf`:

```
play.application.loader = "CustomApplicationLoader"
```

Full code example:
https://github.com/webjars/webjars-play/tree/cicular-deps